# Efficiently displaying and hiding specific job comments with associated IDs on button click

Tags: reactjs, loops, pivot-table

How can I implement a functionality where, upon clicking a button, only the comments associated with a specific job (based on its ID) are displayed? Additionally, if a list of comments is already open and the button is clicked to hide it, how can I ensure that only the corresponding list of comments is affected? I have attempted several solutions, but I am currently facing difficulties. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    const show_comments=(item,index)=>{
     
     setCurrentcomment(item.id);
     setIsVisible(!isVisible);
    }

<li><a title="" class="com" onClick={() => {show_comments(item,index)}}>

{(item.id === currentComm && isVisible==true) && (
     <div  className={`comment-section`} >
     <div class="comment-sec">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <div class="comment-list">
                     <div class="bg-img">
                         <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40" alt=""/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="comment">
                         <h3>John Doe</h3>
                         <span><img src="images/clock.png" alt=""/> 3 min ago</span>
                         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus hendrerit metus, ut ullamcorper quam finibus at.</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 {/* <!--comment-list end--> */}
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     {/* <!--comment-sec end--> */}
     
     {/* <!--post-comment end--> */}
     </div> 
                                                 )}
```